# How would I modify my vector field centered at origin and make it repeat at each integer on the x axis?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, circles, vector-fields, parametrization

I have my vector field $X=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$, which leaves me with a circular vector field with center at origin(as can be seen in the picture below)

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to modify said vector field for it to still maintain the circular direction but for it to repeat at each integer along the x axis?

I have tried by modifying my $x$ value to a $cos(x)$ for it to repeat along the x-axis. I have tried:

$X=(\frac{-y}{cos(x*pi)^2+y^2},\frac{cos(x*pi)}{cos(x*pi)^2+y^2})$

and

$X=(\frac{-y}{cos(x)^2+y^2},\frac{cos(x)}{cos(x)^2+y^2})$

Both have not given me the results I am looking for (they did repeat the circular patterns I wanted but they did not repeat at each integer as I wanted). What I'm I missing? How should I modify my vector field? Is there an additional parametrization I have to do?

Comment: Do you mean that the magnitudes of the vectors should quickly drop to zero everywhere except at integer x? Have you tried multiplying the vectorfield with some kind of wave? (Also why do you call the second component x, that is usually y)

Comment: No, I am looking for a vector field that has circular flux with a center point on each integer along the x axis. In other words, a field with repeating circle patterns of the same magnitude. The center of said circle pattern should be each whole number on the x axis.

Comment: So when you say x you mean radius?

Comment: Not really, there isn't a radius per say, as there are no boundaries nor curves in the problem yet. The flow of the vector field should be circular and repeat itself at each integer (which the circular flow's center at (x,0) for x=integer). It is basically a modified repeating cos vector field, however I do not know how to write it.

Comment: Okay I think I understood you know, you want sources of circles at each $(x_i, 0)$ coordinate?

Comment: Yes exactly! I am looking for a vector field that would do that

Comment: Since they seem to fall off fairly quickly i would probably try to make a sum of vector fields where you change the sources to be shifted, something like mapping $x$ to $x-x_i$. If that doesn't work I think you'll need to wait for some other person to help.